# Delete a Record Using Visualforce

Tags: visualforce, dml

I tried this code i m getting error like this

> "List has no rows for assignment to SObject"

---

```
public class delrecords {
  public string cid{get;set;}
  public list<contact> conlist{get;set;}
  public contact con{get;set;}

  public list<contact> getcontacts(){
    conlist = [select id,firstname,lastname,email from contact where (owner.id =: userinfo.getuserid())];
    return conlist; 
  }

  public void deletecon(){
    con = [select id,firstname,lastname,email from contact where id=:cid];
    delete con;
  }
}
```

---

Comment: from the page you are assigning the value to the variable **cid** , but in the apex controller method you are using the variable **conid** to get the contact

Comment: i changed contact id conid to cid still its not working getting same error "list has no rows fos assignment to sobject".....

Comment: please any one give me solution for this

Comment: system.debug your conid/cid value in your apex and see if its populating.

Comment: no its not populating returning 0 contact records in debug log

Comment: If you have in your VF something like- <apex:commandLink value="Delete Me" action="{!deleteCon}">
                        <apex:param assignTo="{!cid}" name="cid" value="{!contact.id}"/> 
                     
                    </apex:commandLink>Then I would have thought you'd be ok.

Comment: Check in the debug logs if there is a reference to deleteCon() and before that a set parameter statement for the cid value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you the error if no records match:

```
con = [select id,firstname,lastname,email from contact where id=:cid];
```

Instead, do

```
List<Contact> cons = [select id,firstname,lastname,email from contact where id=:cid]; 
if(cons.size() > 0) { delete cons[0]; }
```